# Prove $\tan(\alpha/2)\tan(\beta/2)\tan(\gamma/2)\tan(\delta/2)+[\frac{(1+e)}{(1-e)}]^2 =0$

Tags: conic-sections, 3d, polar-coordinates

If the normals at the points of vectorial angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ on

the conic $l/r=1+e\cos\theta$

meet at a point, then prove that

$\tan(\alpha/2)\tan(\beta/2)\tan(\gamma/2)\tan(\delta/2)+(\frac{1+e}{1-e})^2 =0$

Also prove that if the normals meet at a point $(\rho,\phi)$, then

$\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta-2\phi=$ odd multiple of $\pi$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Equation of normal to the given conic at a point whose vectorial angle is $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are
$$\frac{le \sin\alpha}{1+e \cos\alpha}r = e\sin\theta+\sin(\theta-\alpha)$$
And
$$\frac{le \sin\beta}{1+e \cos\beta}r = e\sin\theta+\sin(\theta-\beta) $$respectively

Subtracting these equation and solving We get
$$r\cos(\theta-\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2})=\frac{l(1-e^2)\cos\frac{(\beta-\alpha)}{2}}{(1–e\cos\alpha)](1-e\cos\beta)}$$

How to obtain $\tan\frac{\alpha}{2}\tan\frac{\beta}{2} = \frac{1+e}{1–e}$from above results

Am i in the right path?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How to prove required results